# Reported failure to import Careers Profile to Developer Story

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, cv-import

I just tried the import option as prompted.

*It seems like you have a Careers profile. Import the data and we'll fill out most of your story for you.*

---

A pink error panel appeared with *One or more items could not be imported to your developer story. Please try again later.*

However, it seems to have done a fairly comprehensive job of importing [my story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/53870).

So that leaves me wondering: *what's missing* and **when** is *later*?

Thoughts on what could be explained more clearly or enhanced:

- Is there a 1-1 match between the content of Careers profiles and the story? Is the story a pure superset? The *we'll fill out most of your story for you* is ambiguous.
- Could *One or more items* be more specific as to at least category of item and quantity?
- If there is a tendency to fail because of typical content in specific parts of the data, we could help focus on problems if we had **control over what to import**.
- There's no undo. If I have imported a ton of material and decide I don't like most of it, how can I back out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your report.

Your story failed due to our super fancy algorithm for coming up with a Title for you, based on your CV and experiences. I forgot to ensure that the length of such title was smaller than the MaxTitleSize, which resulted in an exception being thrown. This has now been fixed and hopefully you'll be able to import your CV with our next build.

We will also make sure to explain properly what happened during the import (including what went wrong and what went right) as you suggested. Thanks for beta testing this for us <3

Comment: After 30+ years in a weird range of roles and platforms, **I** have trouble coming up with a title! cheers

Comment: Yes, [titles can be quite tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/teams/135/stack-overflow-careers).

Comment: @rla4 Unfortunately, I'm also reproducing the import problem in my profile page with the same message. Has the fix already been released? If so, my case might have fell into a different issue. BTW, hey, Roberta, nice to meet you! :)

Comment: Hm, similar problem, different place. Investigating (oh, nice to meet you too!)

Comment: @falsarella mind to try again? There was a mismatch on the size of the Tags column on the Careers DB vs the SO DB. Should be good now.

Comment: @rla4 [Didn't work =/](http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/story/import/1064325). (Or, it worked - but had another problem)

Comment: @falsarella wow, you just uncovered an interesting one. The URL to one of your top answers include special characters that we are not parsing correctly. This is a bug that apparently has been around for ~700 days! I'll let you know once it's fixed, thanks for your report again <3

Comment: @rla4 Wow! Great :) FIY: now I can't even get in [my profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1064325/falsarella) O.o' - but let's wait for the fix. Thanks for the update!

Comment: @falsarella yes, that was part of the bug. The import worked just fine, but it brought one of [your Top Answers along](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72288/esperar-vari%C3%A1vel-ser-definida-para-abrir-sinaleiro/72298#72298). When showing your Developer Story, we try to parse the Top Answer Id from the URL, and our regex was broken for special characters. I fixed the regex, and you should be able to access your story now. Phew!

Comment: @rla4 Perfect! Everything's fine now. Nice work! Thank you! <3